# selective inheritence from templated class based on existence of its full specialization

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

OK, I'm new to templates in C++ and maybe this code is full of bad design, but here it goes.

I needed to deduce type of some objects at run-time and display the types visually(e.g. as string or different colours etc.). This is because of parsing an external file and hence I can only know about the type of the objects at run-time. So I coded it this way

Base property type

```cpp
class BaseProperty {
    std::string name;
public:
    enum class Type {
        A, B //C,D... many more
    };
    BaseProperty(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}
    virtual ~BaseProperty() {}
    virtual std::string get_name() const { return name; }
    virtual Type get_type() const = 0;
    virtual void size() const = 0;
    virtual size_t get_cardinality() const = 0;
};
```

Templated specialized property types for different cardinal types e.g. A2, B3 etc. A2 is a collection of 2 A's, B3 is collection of 3 B's and so on.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class ChildProperty : public BaseProperty {
    std::vector<T> val;
public:
    ChildProperty(const std::vector<T>& val, const std::string& name = "") 
    : val(val), BaseProperty(name) {}
    virtual ~ChildProperty();
    virtual void size() const override { return val.size(); }
    virtual Type get_type() const override;
    virtual size_t get_cardinality() const override;
};

template<>
BaseProperty::Type ChildProperty<A>::get_type() const {
    return BaseProperty::Type::A;
}

template<>
size_t ChildProperty<A>::get_cardinality() const {
    return 1;
}

template<>
BaseProperty::Type ChildProperty<A2>::get_type() const {
    return BaseProperty::Type::A;
}

template<>
size_t ChildProperty<A2>::get_cardinality() const {
    return 2;
}

template<>
BaseProperty::Type ChildProperty<B>::get_type() const {
    return BaseProperty::Type::B;
}

template<>
size_t ChildProperty<B>::get_cardinality() const {
    return 1;
}

template<>
BaseProperty::Type ChildProperty<B3>::get_type() const {
    return BaseProperty::Type::B;
}

template<>
size_t ChildProperty<B3>::get_cardinality() const {
    return 3;
}
```

The classes would be used this way

```cpp
class User {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseProperty>> props;
public:
    void add_prop(std::unique_ptr<BaseProperty> a) {
        props.push_back(std::move(a));
    }
    void do_something_for_every_prop() {
        for(const auto& prop : props) {
            show_number_of_props(prop->size());
            show_type_visually(prop->get_type(), prop->get_cardinality());
        }
    }
};
User u;
u.add_prop(std::make_unique<ChildProperty<A2>>(std::vector<A2>{...}, "A2"));
u.add_prop(std::make_unique<ChildProperty<B>>(std::vector<B>{...}, "B"));
u.do_something_for_every_prop();
```

Now I need to add a second type of property that is mostly same as BaseProperty for A, B etc. types but can also accommodate some different cardinal types e.g. A2x2, B4x3 etc. I want to do something like

```cpp
class ExtendedBaseProperty : public BaseProperty {
public:
    ExtendedBaseProperty(const std::string& name) : BaseProperty(name) {}
    virtual ~ExtendedBaseProperty();
    virtual bool is_matrix() const = 0;
    virtual std::pair<size_t, size_t> matrix_dim() const = 0;
};

// for A, B.. the templated ExtendedChildProperty should inherit from 
// corresponding ChildProperty specializations
template<>
class ExtendedChildProperty<A> 
: public ExtendedBaseProperty, public ChildProperty<A> {
    virtual bool is_matrix() const override {
         return false;
    }
    virtual std::pair<size_t, size_t> matrix_dim() const override {
         return std::make_pair(0, 0);
    }
}
// ...same for A2, B3
// for A2x2, B4x3 etc. they should only inherit from ExtendedBaseProperty
template<>
class ExtendedChildProperty<A2x2> 
: public ExtendedBaseProperty {
    virtual Type get_type() const override {
        return BaseProperty::Type::A;
    }
    virtual size_t get_cardinality() const override {
        return 4;
    }
    virtual bool is_matrix() const override {
         return true;
    }
    virtual std::pair<size_t, size_t> matrix_dim() const override {
         return std::make_pair(2, 2);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use some combination of `std::enable_if`,`std::is_same` etc. to generate the code for this conditional inheritence with templates instead of having to write each of them for each specialized cardinal types?
Thanks for patience and help in advance.

Comment: Note that a mathematical vector can be seen as a matrix [1, N].

Comment: @Jarod42 I've to store the properties parsed from a file in a list of generic type, then display the properties while iterating over the list. How would I query the generic type about whether it's a scalar, vector or matrix? If I know it's a matrix or a vector then only I can reliably perform indexing operations, right?

Comment: From generic point of view, you can treat the same same way `Matrix<N, M>`, `Matrix<1, N>` ("vector"), `Matrix<1, 1>` ("scalar"). It may seems less intuitive to do matrix access for scalar, but it may allow simpler code.

Comment: Okay, yeah, that can be done, but I've to define new types for matrices then because there probably isn't a A1x1 or B1x3 defined in the library. They're made out of structs instead of arrays. :(